# Why does preventDefault on the dragstart event leave the element selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to prevent any drag/drop on my page utilizing the following Javascript:

```
document.addEventListener('dragstart', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Unfortunately, even this does prevent the drag/drop behavior as intended, the element which was dragged stays selected (as if the mouse was hovering over the element) until another element is selected.

For example, if I click and drag over "AD CONFIG" you can see it still appears as if the mouse is over the link:

[image: Link remains selected]

How can I go about disabling drag and drop whilst still firing the appropriate events to prevent the above behavior from occurring?

EDIT: Here's a Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/pWZqe7uohqlVxMwyAS4d?p=preview

Comment: Let me see if I can put one together quickly.

Comment: that is likely due to `:active`  css

Comment: @slashp Btw, why not using CSS no select instead?

Comment: @IonicăBizău CSS no select does not appear to prevent the drag and drop--I've added "* { -webkit-touch-callout:none; -webkit-user-select:none; -khtml-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; -o-user-select: none; user-select: none; }" to my style.css to no avail.

Comment: _“I am attempting to prevent any drag/drop on my page”_ – what for? (Serious question!)

Comment: This is an desktop nw.js Angular application so I would like to abstract as much of the "web browser" away as possible if that makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess it's pretty much related to the browser behavior. You can hack it this way, using `:hover` to add the `underline`:

```
#status-buttons a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#status-buttons a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```js
// Code goes here
document.addEventListener('dragstart', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

/* Numbered buttons */

#status-buttons {} #status-buttons a {
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#status-buttons a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#status-buttons a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#status-buttons span {
  background: #222222;
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
#status-buttons a.active span {
  background: #0099CC;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="status-buttons" class="text-center">
    <a class="active" href="#">
      <span></span> Authenticate</a>
    <a href="#">
      <span></span> Target Disk</a>
    <a href="#">
      <span></span> AD Config</a>
    <a href="#">
      <span></span> Network Options</a>
    <a href="#">
      <span></span> Imaging</a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm guessing you're correct about this being related to browser behavior.  This solution does appear to work properly.  Thank you Ionică.